# Mainform textbox referencing combo box in subform on Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, textbox

Quick question to do with Microsoft access. I've only been using it for about a week, so theres a lot i dont know.

I have a form with a sub form in it. In the sub form there is a combo box. When the user selects a value in the sub form combo box, i want the mainform's textbox to show what the user picked from the combo box.

I dont think it should be very hard to do, i just have no idea of what the code should be. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the After Update event of the subform combo and refer to the main form as `Me.Parent`. Your code might look like this:

```
 Me.Parent.txtTextBox = Me.cboCombo
```